# Identity Manager SignOutAsync Session Still Alive Server-Side

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

If a user saves their cookies, logs out, and then imports their cookies back into their browser they are logged in successfully. How can I make `SigninManager` kill their session server-side also? I read about abandon but it doesn't seem available.

This is my code:

```
await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
HttpContextAccessor httpCon = new HttpContextAccessor();
httpCon.HttpContext.Session.Clear();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the normal process. To invalidate the identity cookie after signout, you could update the `SecurityStamp` and check it by following steps below:

1. `CustomCookieAuthenticationEvents`

   ```
   public class CustomCookieAuthenticationEvents : CookieAuthenticationEvents
   {
       private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;

       public CustomCookieAuthenticationEvents(SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager)
       {
           // Get the database from registered DI services.
           _signInManager = signInManager;
       }

       public override async Task ValidatePrincipal(CookieValidatePrincipalContext context)
       {
           var userPrincipal = context.Principal;

           var user = await _signInManager.ValidateSecurityStampAsync(userPrincipal);

           if (user == null)
           {
               context.RejectPrincipal();

               await context.HttpContext.SignOutAsync(
                   IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Register and configure `CustomCookieAuthenticationEvents`

   ```
   services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
       .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
       .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
   services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
   {
       options.EventsType = typeof(CustomCookieAuthenticationEvents);
   });
   services.AddScoped<CustomCookieAuthenticationEvents>();
   ```
3. SignOut Process

   ```
   await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
   var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
   await _userManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(user);
   _logger.LogInformation("User logged out.");
   ```